# ElasticsearchClientException: Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 403 from: POST /index/

Tags: elasticsearch, .net-core, aws-lambda, nest, serverless

I am having a problem executing a lambda that makes calls to a public ES in the context of AWS. This lambda is executed by HTTP API Gateway events. Everything seems to indicate that it is a permissions issue of the lambda trying to access the ES but my serverless configuration seems valid:

```
service: my-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: dotnetcore2.1
  stage: ${opt:stage, "Development"}
  region: ${opt:region, "us-east-1"}

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "lambda:invokeFunction"
      Resource: "*"    
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - es:ESHttpPost
        - es:ESHttpPut
        - es:ESHTTPGet
      Resource: "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:account:domain/domain-name/*"


  environment:
    ES_ENDPOINT: ${file(appsettings.${self:provider.stage}.json):ES_ENDPOINT}
    STAGE: ${self:provider.stage}
    REGION: ${self:provider.region}

  apiKeys:
    - myservice-api-key 

package:
  individually: true

functions:
  myservice_api:
    handler: com.myservice::com.myservice.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync
    package:
      artifact: bin/release/netcoreapp2.1/myservice.zip
    events:
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors: true
          private: true
```

The error that is logging me is the following:

```
Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful (403) low level call on POST
OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 403 from: POST /index/_search?typed_keys=true
```

Package Versions:
NEST 7.4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. The internal Exception I found was: "`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.`". I solved the issue by changing the version of Elasticsearch.Net.Aws from 6.0.0 to 7.0.4.